# Are id attributes required for lightbox enlarging images?

Tags: javascript, image, lightbox

I'm using lightbox javascript to enlarge an image when its clicked on. I am adding multiple images. If I remove the id attribute associated from the image, it still works when I test it out with firefox v25. To save on room, can I remove the images id attribute? If I have to keep it, should I name each image a different id name?

```
<a style="" href="http://website.com/images/image.jpg" id="image981" onclick="return hs.expand(this, { captionId: 'caption981', dimmingOpacity: 0.75, wrapperClassName: 'rounded-white', outlineType: 'rounded-white', slideshowGroup: 'minigallery', align: 'center', spaceForCaption: 30 } )">
    <img style="visibility: visible;" src="images/image-thumbnail.jpg" class="pic" border="0" height="124" width="165" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to verify, but you're using the JS-library from [highslide.com](http://highslide.com/)?

In that case it's ok to remove the id-attribute. The library doesn't need it.

If you're using the minigallery you only have to use the same name in the *slideshowGroup* parameter for it to work, no need for the id attribute.

Answer (score -1):

It has a minigallery associated with it, so if I want to show multiple images within the enlarged image, I would name each image a different id-attribute name.